# Fuzzy date match

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql db of clients and crawled a website retrieving all the reviews for the past few years. Now I am trying to match those reviews up with the clients so I can email them. The problem is that the review site allowed them to enter anything they wanted for the name, so in some cases I have full first name and last initial, and in some cases first initial and last full name. It also gives an approximate time it was posted such as "1 week ago", "6 months ago" and so on which we already have converted to an approximate date.

Now I need to try matching those up to the clients. Seems the best way would be to do a fuzzy search on the names, and then once I find all `John B%` I look for the one with a job completion date nearest the posting of the review naturally eliminating anything that was posted before jobs were completed.

I put together a small sample dataset where table1 is the clients, table2 is the review to match on here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23928c/6/0

I was initially thinking of doing a date_diff, but then I need to sort by the lowest number. Before I tackle this on my own, I thought I would ask if anyone has any tricks they want to share.

I am using PHP / Laravel to query MySql

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF` with absolute values:

```
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(`date`, $calculatedDate)) DESC
```

To find records that match your estimation closely, positive or negative.